# Extending Option w/reason

Tags: scala

I would like to  be able to pass an optional reason for a "None". I tried just extending 'None' ex:

```
case class NoneReason(reason: String) extends None
```

but get a "not found: type None", then I tried:

```
case class NoneReason(reason: String) extends Option[Nothing] {
    def isEmpty = true
    def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
}
```

but I get a ""illegal inheritance from sealed class Option"

I'm guessing this is a special case because 'None' is actually an alias for null or something.

I considered copying the Option source and renaming it to TriOption or something, but this seems gross to maintain. What would be an elegant way to get around this?

Comment: You could use `Try[T]` or `Either[String, T]` instead of creating your own type.

Comment: There's no special case, `None` is not an alias for anything especially not `null`. All of the `Option` classes are sealed, final, or case objects which is the intent, you shouldn't be able to extend these and you can't. A quick example is `Option(something) match { case Some(x) => ... case None => ... }` which the compiler can check that you've matched all possible cases since `Option` isn't extendable beyond it's base package. As @Lee suggests, you should use a different different data structure like `Either[String, T` which is basically your `NonReason` type.

Comment: Subtyping is not idiomatic FP; also, it makes code more complicated and disables e.g. match-case static exhaustion checks.

Answer (score 4):

An optional reason for `None` is an `Either[Option[String], Foo]`, where `Foo` is your type.  You can't extend `None`; it's a singleton, so you can consider it to be a value like `null`.

But the `Either` class is made to select between two alternatives, with the right branch by convention containing a "correct" answer (if one is more correct than the other).  If you want an optional error message, that goes in the left branch.  Thus, you can switch to the type shown above and then wherever you would normally use `Option` you can `x.right.toOption` to convert to an option without a message, or use pattern matching or whatever, e.g.

```
x match {
  case Right(foo) => useFoo(foo)
  case Left(None) => throw new Exception("Something went wrong.")
  case Left(Some(msg)) => throw new Exception(msg + " went wrong.")
}
```

If you find this to have too much boilerplate, you could use [ScalaUtils](http://www.scalautils.org/) or [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) or any of a number of other libraries that have an Option-with-reason alternative.  ScalaUtils is really easy to get up to speed with.  Scalaz is much deeper, which if you need the depth is awesome and if you don't means that it takes longer to start being productive.

Answer (score 0):

None is not alias to null.  it is an object (singleton) which extends Option[Nothing].
The reason you cannot extend it is that Option is sealed class, which mean it can be extends only by classes in the same file as the sealed class.
The way to go is, as Lee wrote in the comment to your question, is to use `Try[T]` or `Either[String, T]`.
[Here](http://mauricio.github.io/2014/02/17/scala-either-try-and-the-m-word.html) some nice explanation of how to use them.